# How to fix: When I try to print the value of a double, it outputs the value rounded-down

Tags: java, double

Consider the following code snippet:

```java
    int[] dataSet = {1,2,3,4};
    int total = 0;
    for(int temp : dataSet){
        total += temp;
}

    double mean = (total / dataSet.length);
    System.out.println(mean);
```

I expected this to output 2.5, as that is the mean of 1,2,3,4. Instead, it printed 2.0. Why is this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java 7 or more if you use a int / int you have a int

Try to cast one number to double.

double res = 1 / (double) 2;

Comment: This helped a lot! Thanks!